# Correct approach to display navigation properties in asp.net mvc using html helpers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have this classes:

```
public class Bar
{
    public string Name;
}

puclic class Foo
{
    public string Age {get;set;}
    public List<Bar> Bars {get;set;}
}
```

I want to display in Foo View infomations about each of its Bar, for example:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Bars.ElementAt(1).Bar.Name)
```

Is this the correct approach using Razor/Html Helpers? If i change the value of Bars[1] then post to controlller it will update the value in model? And for last, how i can create dynamically bars using the foo view and assign them to foo's bar list model?

Comment: It needs to be `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Bars[0].Name)` to display the first one, but if you want to display all items in the collection, use a `for` loop or `EditorTemplate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display all `Bar` items (and be able to submit to a POST method with parameter `Foo model`, then you need a `for` loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < Model.Bars.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Bars[i].Name)
}
```

or (better), use an `EditorTemplate` for typeof `Bar`

`/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Bar.cshtml`

```
@Model.Bar
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
```

and in the main view

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Bars)
```

The `EditorFor()` method will generate the correct html for each item in your collection

To dynamically add and remove `Bar` items, refer to [POST a form array without successful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796) and [Submit same Partial View called multiple times data to controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308)

Comment: Thanks for your time